# How to bypass rendering the parent template in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a hierarchy of nested routes in my ember app. I want one of the child routes to bypass rendering it's parent template and render directly into the application template. However, I still want to keep the route hierarchy, because I need the models from the parent routes in the child route. What I did is I defined the `renderTemplate` hook on the child route to render into the `application`:

```
renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render({ into: "application" });
}
```

This works, but when I then click on a link to the parent route, nothing is rendered. I put together a small jsfiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/H7gvz/1/ - run it, then click on one of the names, then click on "Index". I expect the `PeopleRoute` to render the `people` template but instead nothing is rendered.

Is this a bug or am I doing it totally wrong? What should be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you use nested routes, transitioning from child route ('people.show') to parent route ('people'), will be redirected to the 'index' route. Rendering your 'people' template in App.PeopleIndexRoute will solve your problem.

```
App.PeopleIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('people',{ into: "application" });

}  
});
```

Your working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7gvz/2/)

Comment: This seems to work for the simple jsfiddle I put together, but unfortunately, it doesn't for the actual case in the project I'm working on. There I have more complicated route hierarchy several levels deep. However, in the end, I managed to find a way to pull the original child route out from the original parent, so I don't have to bypass the parent template rendering anymore. I'm still accepting your answer though, because it solves the question the way I formulated it.